# How to extract filename from string in vimscript?

Tags: vim, arguments, filenames

Say we are given this string in a vimscript:

`"/home/Linus Torvalds/.vim/bundle/vim-autoformat/formatters/tidy -q --show-errors 0 --show-warnings 0 --indent auto --indent-spaces 2 --vertical-space yes --tidy-mark no --wrap 68"`.

How do we extract the filename part? In this case that would be:

`"/home/Linus Torvalds/.vim/bundle/formatters/tidy"`.

Comment: Why do you need this? It's far better to build such a command from its elements than to try to deconstruct it later. Code smell alert!

Comment: I saw your path has spaces, then why not dash `-`? so I think the filename would be `/home/Linus Torvalds/.vim/bundle/formatters/tidy -q --show` or even `/home/Linus Torvalds/.vim/bundle/formatters/tidy -q -` are there any rules for your filename?

Comment: I cannot guarantee that there are no dashes in the filename. I changed the example to point that out immediately. The path is given by the user. @IngoKarkat That's why I don't build it up from its elements. It's a customizable configuration, and I need to check wether the given formatprg is executable.

Comment: You can still make both executable and its arguments customizable - as separate variables.

Comment: Well yeah, that's an option I think. However, it would be elegant to have a setting being defined in one variable only. But you think that's not possible?

Comment: If dashes are allowed in the path I don't think it is (reliably) possible to identify the end of the path and the start of the options, as @Kent pointed out. In your example, how do we know there isn't a directory or file named `tidy -q`? I think the two-variable approach is much better. Maybe you could supply a default set of options to make this simpler in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

If you can guarantee there are no dashes (`-`) in the path itself, I would do it like this:

```
matchstr(input_string,'^.\{-}\ze -')
```

Explanation: From the beginning of the string (`^`) match any character non-greedily (`.\{-}`) until the first occurrence of a space followed by a dash (`\ze -`).

Or you could just match until the first dash and then trim any trailing whitespace with a `substitute()` command, which would be less concise, but might be more readable.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I cannot guarantee that the path has no dashes however. I will change the example to point that out.